# Does Csh have an autocomplete setting that deal better with case?

Tags: autocomplete, csh

I have auto complete turned on in my .cshrc:

```
    set autolist
    set correct=cmd
    set complete=enhance
```

works pretty nicely, except when it comes to case.

I have a directory that contains these files:

```
ToolConfig.pm*      ToolConfig.pm_bak*  Toolconfig_init.pm* 
ToolConfig.pm.orig* ToolConfig.pm~*
```

At the prompt, I type, "tool -tab-" and it gives me:
Toolconfig

ok. I then type ".pm", yielding Toolconfig.pm

at this point, it sure would be nice to hit -tab- again and have it finish the job by making upcasing the 'c'. I have a complete filename, sure there are additional possibilities, but for the current sting, I have to move the cursor back to do it myself.

Kinda negates some of the utility of completion.

Surely, I am not along in this frustration. There must be some special sauce to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the 'set complete=enhance" you'll get a case-sensitive Tab completion, so that typing "T[tab]" expands to "Tool" at which point you can choose an upper- or lower-case 'c'.

In order to see the change, you'll have to unset 'complete' or logout and login.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried set complete=Enhance with upper case "**E**" instead of "enhance".
From the man page, I read:
If  the complete shell variable is set to `Enhance', completion ignores case and
differences between a hyphen and an underscore word separator only when the user
types  a lowercase character or a hyphen.  Entering an uppercase character or an
underscore will not match the corresponding lowercase character or  hyphen  word
separator.

This gives a little better completion that the "enhance" in my use cases.
Give it a try and let us know if any better...

Answer (score 0):

I know it probably not the answer you wanted, but **bash** is better at this.  With
`set completion-ignore-case on`
it does what you want.